# Custom control: objectchoicefield with image and text

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to create an ObjectChoiceField where each element has a bitmap and a text label. The image and the label would be shown on the "button" portion of the field and also on its associated row in the popup menu.

This control would be identical in look and feel to the Downloads folder field found in the Settings at Display --> Home Screen Preferences under the "Downloads Folder" section.

[image]

I have my bitmaps and labels ready to go but am stuck in the implementation of the control.

If I simply override the paint method of ObjectChoiceField, it does nothing to the popup menu...

I want the control to respect the default BB look and feel of ObjectChoiceField.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to change the way the choices are displayed, on the choice field *and* its popup menu, then you're really **not** respecting the default BB look and feel.  I'm pretty sure you're going to have to extend `Field`, and write your own custom class, from scratch.

Comment: Yes that's what I figured it would turn out to be. However, I want to mimick the exact look... Any sample code I can use?

Comment: I very much doubt you'll find anything.  Simply adding the image to the field itself (by overriding `paint()`) probably isn't too difficult, but rewriting the entire field from scratch just to *also* get the image into the popup is a ton of work for very little benefit ... so, I'm guessing you won't find anything that goes that far.